# http redirect shows a 302 but should be 301

Tags: iis, redirect, url-rewriting, web-config

I have a site that uses SSL. 
When I correct to the default (http://www.example.com), it supposed to load http://www.example.com

And it does, but when I use a redirect checker, I notice this:

```
www.accufinance.com

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private,no-transform
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://www.accufinance.com/
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 18 Sep 2014 00:20:43 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 145

https://www.accufinance.com/
```

My site in on a shared host, so I used a web.config redirect.

In that, I have:

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="mypath/mysite/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
```

Note: Since posing, I changed `type="Rewrite"` to `type="Redirect"`, but no in the result. Still seems to be a 302.

So I am expecting a 301 - permanently moved, and, hoping not to see a "Not found".

What could be wrong here?

Comment: First of all, `302 - Found` is not the same as "Not found". But a 302 is not the same as a 301, so something's still wrong. What does your `<match>` look like, and are you sure it matches the URL?

Comment: Did you ever solve it?